# How do I allow CORS requests on mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I tried adding `$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains = array( '*' );` to LocalSettings.php, but didn't work.

I am trying to add content created by an external server. The snippet below shows how I want to show the value of a parameter (I am planning to serve more complex content that I can only build on the external server.)

I added the following code to MediaWiki:Common.js:

```
$.each($('.from-outside'), 
       function(index, element) {
         element = $(element);
         paramName = element.attr('param-name');
         console.log('Loading ' + paramName + '...');
         element.load('http://outside.domain/get_value/' + encodeURIComponent(paramName));
       });
```

Then the following content on a template:

```
<html>
<div class="from-outside" param-name="param one"><i>Loading...</i></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried adding `$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains = array( '*' );` to LocalSettings.php

Please don't. That's like disabling password checks on login.

Assuming you put something more reasonable in there, this is the right way to allow CORS. Given that the rest of your question does not seem to be related to enabling CORS, it's hard to tell what's not working. (Are you maybe misunderstanding in which direction CORS works? If a script on your wiki makes a request to `outside.domain`, it is `outside.domain` that needs to allow CORS.)

Comment: Yes, I was misunderstanding. I assumed that the wiki server should accept data only from known sources by declaring those sources in the server. Thanks for pointing out that I was opening a hole on my wiki.